# Laravel 5.3 Save related model with array

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a User model and Event model.

A User can have/create many Events

An Event belongs to User.

I have made this form just for demo:

[image]

And i get this output when i dd($request);

[image]

How to save this in my database table events.
These array fields are problem...do i need to make some new table except users and events??

Comment: What is the problem with the array?

Comment: How do you save an array in one line?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it looks like you need another table. I've just taken an educated guess at the table names because I'm not 100% sure what these times and professions refer to, it looks like you already have a table storing the professions, but here are the relationships I can see:

- `A user can have many events`
- `An event belongs to a user`
- `An event has many timeslots`
- `A timeslot belongs to an event`
- `A profession has many timeslots`
- `A timeslot has many professions`

So your events and professions (don't worry if you've called it something else) table should look like:

> events(id, user_id, name, start, end);
>
> professions(id, profession,..);

And you need to add an extra table:

> time_slots(id, event_id, profession_id, amount, from, to, hours)

Then set those relationships up inside your models.

**EDIT**

The basic way to make a store method is to use the relationships like so:

```
public function store(Request $request){
   // Get the request as an array
   $request = $request->all();
   // create a new event
   $event = Event::create($request);
   
   // Map timeslots to an array of Timeslot objects:
  $timeslots = array_map(function($personalId, $amount, $from, $to, $hours) {
      return new App\Timeslot($personalId, $amount, $from, $to, $hours);
  }, $request['personal_id'], $request['amount'], $request['from'], $request['to'], $request['hours']);

   // Save all timeslots for the event
   $event->timeslots()->saveMany($timeslots)
}
```

I haven't tried that code, but it should point you inb the right direction. You should take a look at laravel relationships to see how this works:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

Comment: Hi craig, i tried to send you a message on twitter but i don't know if you got it....but anyway i need to see the store method in controller for this form...that is the thing i don't know how to make!

Comment: i need your help please if you are there?

Comment: I did all as you said....now the only thing that is missing is how to save the data from form into DB. The store method

Comment: You are incredible....if  i  had a company i would hire you right away!